# Removing duplication of code - construct event based on if else

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which is working as expected is there any way i can reduce the number of lines or functionality so that it can be more modular.

The concerns are I'm calling the exponea track event twice I was wondering is there any way I can construct it once and pass parameters to that based on if else condition. I'm learning javascript so looking for any code optimization

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var categorycollection = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.pipa').getAttribute('data-globaltargeting'));

        var isprofessional = (categorycollection['Type'] == 'PatientPlusArticle') ? 'Yes' : 'No';


        if (categorycollection['Type'] == 'PatientPlusArticle' ||
            categorycollection['Type'] == 'MedicineLeaflet' ||
            categorycollection['Type'] == 'PatientInformationLeaflet') {

            exponea.track('page_visit', {
                "referrer": document.referrer,
                "path": window.location.pathname,
                "category name": document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item')[1].querySelector('span').innerText,
                "Isprofessional": isprofessional

            });

        }
        else {
            
                exponea.track('page_visit', {
                    "referrer": document.referrer
                    , "path": window.location.pathname
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: ``['PatientPlusArticle', 'MedicineLeaflet', 'PatientInformationLeaflet'].includes(categorycollection['Type'])``
one of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator can assign the additional properties when needed - otherwise, use the empty object. Merge the result into the call to `.track`. You can also use `.includes` instead of extracting the Type so many times.

```
const { Type } = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.pipa').getAttribute('data-globaltargeting'));
const additionalObj = ['PatientPlusArticle', 'MedicineLeaflet', 'PatientInformationLeaflet'].includes(Type)
    ? {
        "category name": document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item')[1].querySelector('span').innerText,
        Isprofessional: Type == 'PatientPlusArticle' ? 'Yes' : 'No'
    } : {};
exponea.track('page_visit', {
    referrer: document.referrer,
    path: window.location.pathname,
    ...additionalObj
});
```

The selectors and child indicies are a bit of a code smell, though - I don't know the broader context, but that part probably deserves refactoring too. Otherwise, it'd be very easy for a simple change to the HTML to break everything.